# In Kendo-ui-angular2 Chart, how can I hide a label when the value is null or zero

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo-angular-ui chart and I am displaying labels for each point on a line chart. I don't want to display labels on specific points if the label values are null or zero. How do I go about hiding labels only if null or zero?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is quite late but you can use the content property on the `kendo-chart-series-item-labels` element and bind it to a function in your component that checks the label, and then returns a blank label depending on your conditions.

HTML:

```
<kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item type="donut"
                             [data]="pieData"
                             categoryField="category"
                             field="value">
      <kendo-chart-series-item-labels [content]="labelContent"
                                      [visible]="true">
      </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

And then in your component your function can look something like this:

```
  public labelContent(e: any): string {
    if (e.value === 0) {
      return '';
    }

    return e.value;
  }
```

So quick recap: bind property content on the `kendo-chart-series-item-labels` element to a function in your component that returns a blank value for a label you want to hide.

Comment: Do you know where in the documentation it says such a thing? I find myself quite lost when I browse their documentation.

Comment: I don't think that it is! I just kind of worked it out. Their documentation is not the most comprehensive. You kind of need to patch together some things and I think they assume a rather advanced understanding of Angular and Typescript to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

Component -
`readonly barcodeText: BarcodeText = { visible: false, }`

**HTML**

```html
<ng-template #showBarCode>
    <kendo-barcode [type]="mode" [value]="'12345678901'" [text]="barcodeText"></kendo-barcode>
</ng-template>
```